# VueJS importing local and external script and css files in main file

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to import scripts and css files into the `index.html` file of my vuejs application.
My file structre is as following:

vueapp/
├──index.html
└── src/
       └── assets/
              └── css/
              └── images/
              └── js/
              └── plugins/

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gaming</title>
    <!-- vendor css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/plugins/animate/animate.min.css">
    <!-- plugins css -->
    <link href="/assets/plugins/owl-carousel/css/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- theme css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/custom.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.min.js"></script>    
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I try to open one of the files they just load as a vue route and won't show the actual file.
Any ideas?

Comment: this completely depends on how your server is setup.

Comment: I'm using `vue-cli` with webpack

Comment: How are you serving your static files? There needs to be a difference between static file serving and application routes being served.

Comment: then the `static` folder is probably what you should use. https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/static.html

Comment: @JacobGoh thanks, I'll look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use existing CSS file, then put your CSS file in `/static` folder and edit your URL to `/static/path/to/css`.

Assets folder cannot be accessed from URL (because it's not static).